# Nullable Double Type-Hint

Tags: clojure, nullable, type-hinting

I'm writing a neural net, and have the following definition of a Node:

```
(defrecord Node [^double input-sum ^double last-output])
```

`input-sum` is the running sum of it's input; pre-activation. `last-output` is it's activated value.

My original thought was to create an initial node like `(->Node 0 nil)`. My rational was it didn't make any sense to give the `last-output` a real value before it had ever been activated.

Unfortunately, creating the above Node yields a NPE; apparently because it's attempting to cast the `nil` as a double:

```
(->Node 0 nil)
NullPointerException   clojure.lang.RT.doubleCast (RT.java:1298)
```

If I remove the type-hint on `last-output`, it works fine.

I'm trying to get into the habit of type-hinting what I can. Is there a way to provide the type-hint on `last-output`, but also indicate that `nil` is an acceptable value?

Comment: Could you explain in more detail why you are "trying to get into the habit of type-hinting"? Doing so is a premature optimization, which, as I'm sure you've heard many times, is the root of all evil.

Comment: @SamEstep I figured it would be easier to do it from the start when I'm defining the types instead of down the road

Comment: But you don't know whether you'll actually need to do it down the road. As the [reference documentation](http://clojure.org/reference/java_interop#typehints) states, type hints are purely performance optimizations for "performance-critical areas of code", so what you're doing is a textbook example of premature optimization. I'd strongly encourage you to read the answers to [these](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/80084) [three](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/33020) [questions](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/99445) if you haven't already.

Comment: @SamEstep OK thanks. Maybe I'll just enable to reflection warning and deal with it then, and check out the mentioned packages for documentation.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with adding type hints after you've already written your code, benchmarked it, and found that the reflection is a bottleneck. The problem is when you handicap your design by using them before you know they are needed. As for documentation, I would personally recommend [`clojure.spec`](http://clojure.org/about/spec); it's in the standard library, so it's going to be the best-supported option going forward, and it has a very solid design and a lot of really awesome features.

Comment: Note that `clojure.spec` is only available in 1.9 alpha releases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need to typehint with a primitive type, and using object type `Double` is not an option (like for performance related reason), the common practice (as far as i know) is to create your own custom constructor function:

```
user> (defrecord Node [^double input-sum ^double last-output])
user.Node

user> (defn make-node [^Double input-sum ^Double last-output]
        (->Node (or input-sum 0) (or last-output 0)))
#'user/make-node

user> (make-node nil 0)
#user.Node{:input-sum 0.0, :last-output 0.0}

user> (make-node 10 nil)
#user.Node{:input-sum 10.0, :last-output 0.0}

user> (make-node 1 2)
#user.Node{:input-sum 1.0, :last-output 2.0}
```

the approach is used for all the cases, where you need some sophisticated logic for the entity construction.

**update**

If you really need *both* a primitive value and the way to distinguish value from "no value", you could use `NaN` for that:

```
user> (defn make-node [^Double input-sum ^Double last-output]
        (->Node (or input-sum Double/NaN) (or last-output Double/NaN)))
#'user/make-node

user> (make-node 1 nil)
#user.Node{:input-sum 1.0, :last-output NaN}
```

so, it is value, and also is the primitive analogue of `nil`.

Comment: But this isn't what he was asking... converting `nil` to `0.0` is not the same as "indicat[ing] that `nil` is an acceptable value".

Comment: Right, it is not. But still, if you have a primitive type hint, it is your only option if you don't want to check all the arguments every time you use `->Node`.

Comment: He didn't say "primitive" anywhere in his question, though. Also, his statement that "it didn't make any sense to give the `last-output` a real value before it had ever been activated" seems to imply that he really wants an actual `nil` value, not `0.0` (which is, mathematically speaking, "real").

Comment: But using type hint to "indicate" something (if you mean "to document") looks really strange. There are other instruments for the purpose of type annotation, like `schema`, `spec` or `core.typed`

Comment: Maybe i misunderstood the question then. I thought he needs to use the primitive type hint for optimization, not "some" type hint for documentation

Comment: I interpreted it to mean that he wants to indicate to the *compiler* that `nil` is allowed, so that he doesn't get the `NullPointerException` he's currently getting.

Comment: however, let's wait for the op's comment on this )

Comment: @SamEstep, updated my answer with `NaN` values, which is a bit more relevant to the question, i guess.

Comment: OK, cool. Kind of reeks of C to me, but in cases where primitives are really needed for performance, it works. :)

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question. It's more for documentation; I just generally like having type information. I can see this result becoming a bottleneck though, since the entire net will be composed of nodes that ideally will be firing as fast as possible, so I'd like to avoid boxing. This seems like kind of an abuse of NaN, but I guess it will have to do. Thank you.

Comment: I also didn't know there are packages to help with documentation. I'll look into those. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`^double` is type hint for Java primitive double type. Try `^Double`.

Comment: This was my original thought, but the boxing might become unacceptable.